# What is the relationship between time dilation and gravitational time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time-dilation

This may be a stupid question as I have no background in physics but I'm curious:

We know time stops when approaching the speed of light and also as object approaches the event horizon of a black hole. Sounds like two sides of the same coin.

Are these in any way related / connected or are these entirely different things?

What can be inferred about gravity from time dilation? Is it possible to represent gravitational constant in terms of the speed of light in a nice way?

**Edit**: I'm looking for an answer in layman's terms. The thread above also does not address my last two questions.